# OpenGL ES coordinates to screen pixels

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I am trying to make an advertising application in openGL es 2.0.
Minimizing the problem here, i can explain as an example that I created a rectangle animated cube with having some advertising images on top of it. model and animation is created in 3DS Max and converted into .pod and it is coming in the Tv screen perfectly.

Now I want to know how much screen it is covering in pixels, if my projection is 1280x720, because scaling and translation has been given in the hands of advertiser and he don't know coordinates. advertiser only knows the language of pixels. So if he increase the X axis scale in pixels, I need to convert those to OpenGL coordinates and also have to adjust the translation by myself, so that cube not goes out of screen.

In short, how can I get the no of pixels taken by cube in screen? Is there any easy way?

Comment: From my raytracing project what I can think of this problem is that if you know your projection plane position, your perspective angle and each corner vertex co-ordinates(for maxima and minima) of the object then you can calculate the number of pixels using the equation of intersection between a line and a plane given that translation and scaling factors are known.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `MVP matrix` which gets applied by rendering pipeline to the 'OpenGL coordinates/vertices' to finally extract the screen coordinates.

So it's possible to use it's `inverse` to compute vertices.

Now the problem is multiple combinations of vertices, view and projection matrices can give the same screen coordinates, i.e. the mapping from vertex position to screen coordinates is **not unique**.

So we have **to reduce the unknowns** in the equation to just *x* and *y* by fixing all the other variables (in case of translation) and probably to just *z* (in case of scaling).

For translation, for example, the code could be:

```
Point3D get3dPoint(Point2D point2D, int width,
    int height, Matrix viewMatrix, Matrix projectionMatrix) {

    double x = 2.0 * point2D.x / clientWidth - 1;
    double y = - 2.0 * point2D.y / clientHeight + 1;
    Matrix4 viewProjectionInverse = inverse(projectionMatrix *
         viewMatrix);

    double fixedZ = 1.0;
    Point3D point3D = new Point3D(x, y, fixedZ); 
    return viewProjectionInverse.multiply(point3D);
```

}

Comment: Could you explain what point would this return? in which range and what does it mean to pass 1.0 to z?